# Autoscaling with Amazon ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'll be working with ECS to deploy the containers (both API and Database) of each client. When creating a cluster, it asks me for an instance even though I've always heard about the possibility of autoscaling depending on how much you are actually using. Today we have a client so a t2.micro will do for now but it will continue growing and I'm sure that in little to no time t2.micro won't do the job. How do I autoscale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't autoscale ECS vertically although autoscaling is possible horizontally. 
For a case where you do need to scale vertically, you will have to modify the existing cluster autoscaling group and edit its launch configuration to use the bigger instance type. To do so you can follow the below-mentioned steps:

1. Make a copy of the cluster Launch Configuration and update the 'Instance Type'.
2. Adjust the cluster Auto Scaling Group to point to your new Launch Configuration. NOTE: This will terminate your existing cluster instances.
3. Wait for your new instances to register in your cluster and your services to start.

Hope this helps!